# ¿Como obtener un elemento de una clase por clave sin que TS proteste por la clave?

Tags: typescript

Se tiene la siguiente interfaz:

```
export interface XX{
    Campo1?: string;
    Campo2?: string;
    Campo3?: string;
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

La key es para poder acceder a un elemento de la misma de la forma

```
const p: XX = {};
p['Campo1'];
```

Pero se da el siguiente error de TS

> Property 'Campo1' of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to
>   string index type 'string' (ts 2411)

Anda todo como si nada, asi que no se si es un error de TS por algun bug, o simplemente estoy definiendo algo mal. Como se soluciona ese problema?

El error se da en la definición de la interfaz.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si cambiamos algunos de los string por any, el error para ese campo desaparece.. pero no queremos usar any.

```
export interface XX{
    Campo1?: any; <--- desaparece el error para este campo
    Campo2?: string;
    Campo3?: string;
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

---

Tengo configurado ts de la siguiente forma (extracto)

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
```

Comment: No es `p['Campo1']` en lugar de `p[Campo1]`. En tu código estas haciendo referencia a una variable y no a un string. Es eso correcto?

Comment: Si si.. correcto.. no es por ahi el problema.. ahora lo arreglo.. lo que pasa es que viene de una variable.. error al hacer el mvce...

Comment: Creo que el error aparece por algún tipo de bug de TS por que replique tu código en mi proyecto y no me genera ningún error

Comment: @FRANCISCOJAVIERBLANCOGRAJAL tiene que ver con mi configuracion de ts.. fijate que la agregue

Comment: @gbianchi Yo tengo mi ts de esta forma y no me genera ningun error `{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: El problema es el strict @FRANCISCOJAVIERBLANCOGRAJAL

Comment: Borra el stric  o ponlo en false , y pruebas si no te saca error

Comment: @FRANCISCOJAVIERBLANCOGRAJAL si, por ahi venia el problema...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema está en la última línea de tu definición:

```
export interface XX{
    Campo1?: string;
    Campo2?: string;
    Campo3?: string;
    [key: string]: string; //esta línea
}
```

Si miramos la [documentación](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) vemos lo siguiente:

> While string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the “dictionary” pattern, they also enforce that all properties match their return type. This is because a string index declares that obj.property is also available as obj["property"].

Es decir, si defines que la interfaz tiene propiedades que guardan valores que son `string` (así `[key: string]: string;`), TODAS las propiedades deben cumplir esto. Puesto que `Campo1` tiene un interrogante (puede ser string o undefined), no cumple la condición.

Lo puedes solucionar así:

```
export interface XX{
    Campo1?: string;
    Campo2?: string;
    Campo3?: string;
    [key: string]: string | undefined; 
}
```

Otra opción sería *relajar* las comprobaciones del compilador:

```
"strictNullChecks": false
```

o también

```
"strict": false
```

Comment: o castear el tipo con los guards. y acostumbrarce al tipado: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37978675/4717133

Answer (score 4):

Tienes la opción [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) habilitada. Cuando haces esto cambia la forma en como maneja el typescript los tipos pues normalmente `undefined` es considerado un subconjunto de todos los tipos para asemejarse mejor al comportamiento por defecto del javascript.

En otras palabras, cuando en Typescript dices `a: string` en realidad estas diciendo `a: string | undefined` por lo que este código es perfectamente válido

```
let a: string;
a = undefined;
a = 'string cualquiera'
```

Cuando habilitas modo estricto `undefined` sólo es asignable a si mismo (igual que `null`).

El problema surge entonces de manera indirecta porque estas haciendo que tus propiedades `Campo1`, `Campo2`, etc sean opcionales(`?`) lo cual es lo mismo que decir

```
export interface XX{
    Campo1: string | undefined;
    Campo2: string | undefined;
    Campo3: string | undefined;
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

De hecho si pruebas ese código el error será idéntico.

Si pruebas a quitar los campos opcionales el error desaparece

```
export interface XX{
    Campo1: string;
    Campo2: string;
    Campo3: string;
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

Entonces todo se reduce al hecho que la propiedad indexada `[key: string]: string` coincide también con tus propiedades `Campo1`, `Campo2`, etc y los tipos no son compatibles.

La soluciones que te recomiendo son:

1. Modificar las propiedades para que no sean opcionales
2. Ampliar el tipo a `string | undefined` para la propiedad indexada así su firma coincide con la de los tipos opcionales

   ```
   export interface XX{
       Campo1?: string;
       Campo2?: string;
       Campo3?: string;
       [key: string]: string | undefined;
   }
   ```
3. Eliminar las propiedades `Campo1`, `Campo2`, etc porque de todas maneras tu interfaz es equivalente a usar simplemente esto y cuando todas las propiedades son opcionales el type-checking realmente no ayuda mucho excepto por el intellisense.

   ```
   export interface XX{
       [key: string]: string;
   }
   ```