# TypeScript, problemas para asignar types a una variable que funciona como indexador de un objeto

Tags: typescript

`Data` puede tomar dos valores de tipo objeto donde uno de sus atributos puede cambiar así:

```
data = {

 x: string

 puedo_cambiar: string[]

}

data = {

 x: string

 puedo_cambiar: string[]

}
```

La indexación:

```
const index = Object.keys(data)[1]

data[index].map()
```

No logre darle un `type` a index ninguna forma le gusta a `typescript`

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error de TS? Y `data` parece tener la misma forma en ambos ejemplos, ¿Eso esta bien? saludos

Comment: tu pregunta no es la misma que esta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/272958/324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tipos de acceso indexados

Podemos usar un tipo de acceso indexado para buscar una propiedad específica en otro tipo:

```
type Person = { age: number; name: string; alive: boolean };
type Age = Person["age"];
     
//type Age = number
```

El tipo de indexación es en sí mismo un tipo, por lo que podemos usar uniones keyof, u otros tipos por completo:

```
type I1 = Person["age" | "name"];
     
// type I1 = string | number
 
type I2 = Person[keyof Person];
     
// type I2 = string | number | boolean
 
type AliveOrName = "alive" | "name";
type I3 = Person[AliveOrName];
     
// type I3 = string | boolean
```

Incluso verá un error si intenta indexar una propiedad que no existe:

```
type I1 = Person["alve"];
Property 'alve' does not exist on type 'Person'.
```

**Otro ejemplo de indexación con un tipo arbitrario es usar numberpara obtener el tipo de los elementos de una matriz. Podemos combinar esto con typeofpara capturar convenientemente el tipo de elemento de un literal de matriz:**

```
const MyArray = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 15 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 23 },
  { name: "Eve", age: 38 },
];
 
type Person = typeof MyArray[number];
       
//type Person = {
//    name: string;
//    age: number;
//}
type Age = typeof MyArray[number]["age"];
     
type Age = number
// Or
type Age2 = Person["age"];
      
// type Age2 = number
```

### Solo puede usar tipos al indexar, lo que significa que no puede usar a constante para hacer una referencia de variable:

```
const key = "age";
type Age = Person[key];
//Type 'any' cannot be used as an index type.
//'key' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you //mean 'typeof key'?
```

#### Sin embargo, puede usar un alias de tipo para un estilo similar de refactorización:

```
type key = "age";
type Age = Person[key];
```

Comment: Si hay una clave en esta respuesta en relación a lo que el OP esta buscando conseguir; ahora, si pudieras elaborar la respuesta en relación al problema expuesto en la pregunta sería de mucha ayuda para la comunidad. Esta respuesta se parece a la documentación de `Indexed Access Types` traducida. Saludos